# listed ac motor horsepower doesn't match voltage and amperage

Tags: voltage, motor, amperage

In my search for a bandsaw, I've come across a model that has an AC motor whose plate displays 3/4 Horsepower, but also 115/230 volts, 11.2/5.6 amps. You can see that the math suggests (115 x 11.2 = 1288, 1288 / 746 = 1.7) a horsepower rating which is double what is stated. For the money, I'd much rather assume the higher number. How can the two very different figures be reconciled?

Comment: By considering power factor.

Comment: Additional info: The saw is from 1948. Power factor isn't given, but service factor is 1.25. Also, "SFA" (service factor amps?) is listed as 12.5/6.3.

Comment: [**Here's some help**](https://www.google.com/search?q=service+factor+amps&oq=service+facto&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.8684j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider both efficiency and power factor. Output power = V X A X eff. X pf. 0.44 is not unreasonable for eff. X pf, but it would probably be higher for a modern motor. Service factor is allowable sustained overload. You can operate a motor at the service factor without any immediate bad effects, but it will be running hotter and a lot of operation at the service factor will result in a shorter than expected service life.